# Can my question be undeleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I recently accidentally deleted a question about data structures, but I have insufficient reputation on this site to see deleted questions and so I don't have the ability to undelete it. Would it be possible for someone to nominate it for undeletion, or do I need to repost the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be able to undelete it if you visit the question at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99006/a-data-structure-that-makes-finding-close-objects-easy , and I think [you can find this question in a little corner of your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492#185492) marked “recent deleted questions” under your [list of questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/42401/stella-biderman?tab=questions). See the [deletion FAQ on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222).

Anyway I've undeleted https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99006/a-data-structure-that-makes-finding-close-objects-easy .

Comment: Thank you! I now see that I can see my deleted questions, but I wasn't able to navigate to it because I wasn't aware of the "recently deleted questions" button.